# Get output on shell execute in js with ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, shell, cmd

i tried to get exe file callback result when i doing shell execute like this:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var args = folderName + "\\dir\\scan.exe scan " + params.join(" ");
var ret = oShell.Run(args ,0 ,true);
```

but ret gaves me 0 for fail and 1 for success.
when i run the file in the cmd like this:

scan.exe arg1 arg2 arg3

this is return the correct result that i wanted : "test/test" and not 1...

what can i do?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

I know I might be a bit late to answer this question but I hope it can still help someone.

The way I achieved it was with the `oShell.Exec()` function and not with the `oShell.Run()`.

`oShell.Exec()` returns an object with a property called `StdOut` which acts like a text file, so you can perform `ReadLine()`, `ReadAll()`, etc.

The problem is that it does not wait for the command to end, so when you run your code, it is very likely that your `StdOut` object will be `undefined`. You have to add that waiting option on the command itself.

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

try {
    // Excecute the 'cd' command. 
    wshShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\Users";
    var execOut = wshShell.Exec('cmd /C start /wait /b cd');
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

// Get command execution output.
var cmdStdOut = execOut.StdOut;
var line = cmdStdOut.ReadLine();
console.log(line);
```

The code above will execute a `cd` command on the directory `C:\Users` and store the output on the `line` variable.

I hope this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell to **receive output from BATCH** file:

**script.js**

```
var pathToFile = "your_path_here"
var shell= new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
var output = shell.Exec(pathToFile + 'example.bat');
var response = output.StdOut.ReadLine();
console.log(response)
```

**example.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Hello From Batch World
exit 0
```